# How to change how the axes are controlled on ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the limits set on my axes, but the graph still displays outside of that range. I have the limits of the x axis set from 0.01 to 100, and I'd like the graph to stop right at these values, yet it still has space before and after them. Is there a way to change this?

```
plot<-ggplot(Data, aes(x = Percent, y = Depth, colour = Wavelength)) +
        geom_point() + scale_y_reverse(breaks = c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30), 
        limits = c(30, 0))
plot + scale_x_continuous(trans = "log", breaks = c(100,10,1,0.1,0.01),
       labels = scales::comma, limits = c(0.01, 100))
```

[image: Sample Plot]

Comment: Check out `library(ggplot2);ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() -> p;p + ylim(20,25)` versus `p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(20,25), expand = c(0,0))`. I'm sure it's a duplicate, however I cannot find an appropriate SO question/answer.

Comment: Sure. The answer is `expand = c(0,0)`. It would have been more obvious if you followed the advice that you get, when you hover over the R tag, and provided a reproducible example instead of some Data, which noone has.

Comment: adding the expand = c(0,0) works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `+ xlim(0.01, 100)` which removes data points outside the given range.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm talking about getting rid of the space between  the corner of the graph and 0.01 and the space from 100 to the corner of the graph.